# Twitter Bootstrap: tooltips on html map area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, area

Tooltips from twiiter bootstrap is great, but they didnt work with <area> tags :(
How can I fix it?

I've noticed that js works, tooltip element is created, but it's position is wrong..

I've made a little example.
http://jsfiddle.net/dhkFN/1/

Answer (score 9):

I love Twitter bootstrap but some of the js plugins are a little simple in their current form.

Checkout qTip 2 - http://qtip2.com/

Does everything including image maps - http://qtip2.com/demos/#imagemaps

and you can just adjust the output classes to the bootstrap ones.

Comment: cool plugin, thanks for the heads up. Here is the updated link for the imagemaps feature (it's an add-on now it seems): http://qtip2.com/plugins#imagemap

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar recently with Bootstrap and tried to get tooltips working with image map areas but gave up.

I went with ImageMaster which is a jQuery plugin for making image maps and has options like tooltips etc

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster

ImageMapster did have a few issues with Bootstrap's CSS but the author kindly fixed that issue for me, so it should work great!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Looks like I should get another tooltip library or create fancy tooltips by myself (it is not so hard :))

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching and contemplating on how to solve tooltip (map image using area) for a project I found this http://www.xing.net.au/blogs/displaying-page-in-jquery-tooltip this is more flexible than the JSFiddle when it comes to customizing the content to be displayed.

The sample in JSFiddle is dependent on the ALT attribute of the area while the Jtip can be customize by using another page.

All the best!